# Missing Resource Exception websphere portal

Tags: java, websphere, portal, websphere-portal

`Error 500: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle com.ibm.abc.nl.abcdf, key en_US`.

I am getting this exception. I have the properties file with `abcdf_en` under `com.ibm.abc.nl` package. I am not sure if I have to set my local language in Websphere Portal server or WAS. Is there anything that I am missing ?

Comment: When do get this exception? At runtime or during deployment?

Comment: @UdoHeld At runtime, when the jsp page is loaded. I see this on the page

Comment: Then you should probably show us some code and configuration. If you do it right it should just pick up the other property file.

Answer (score 0):

The message says that `en_US` is the **actual key** that isn't found in the property file. In other words, your property file (`abcdf_en.properties`, inside the `com.ibm.abc.nl` package) is supposed to have a key-value pair there, with the key being `en_US`.

If you have the key `en_US` in there (strange name for a key...), then it means that the `abcdf_en` isn't being picked up. This is either due to the property file not being in the classpath, or that WebSphere Portal doesn't consider `en` to be the current request's locale. Did you try printing out the value of `request.getLocale()`?

If the value of `request.getLocale()` is `null`, that would explain the symptoms you're experiencing.

Comment: Until somebody sets the locale to null, is there any way request.getLocale() will return null? Just curious...

Comment: `request.getLocale()` may return null if the container hasn't defaulted it to any value.